# LINQ Query to get Student Classes

Tags: linq

I have a table student and a table classes and a third table studentclasses having studentid and classic as foreign keys. I want to write a query that allows me to display the following:

```
{
    "code": "10001",
    "Name": "Lola",
    "classes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "class1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "class2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "class3"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: _I want to write a query_ - did you try? or you want us to do your "job" :)

Comment: I did try but it's not working

Comment: from s in db.Students
                         join sc in db.StudentsClasses on s.Student_ID equals sc.Student
                         join c in db.Classes on sc.Class equals c.Class_code
                         select new Student
                         {
                             Student_ID = s.Student_ID,
                             First_Name = s.First_Name,
                             StudentsClasses = List<Class>(c.Class_code, c.Class_Name)
                         }

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question and can you provide more information about what you mean "not working"? Did you get an exception or how you observe that query not working?

Comment: db.Students.ToList().Select(q=>new Student()
            { 
                Student_ID=q.Student_ID,
                First_Name=q.First_Name,
                Classes=q.StudentsClasses.ToList().Select(e=>new Class()
                {
                    Class_code=e.Class,
                    Class_Name=db.Classes.FirstOrDefault(v=>v.Class_code==e.Class).Class_Name
                }).ToList()
            });

I tried the above and everything worked fine thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/data/StudentClasses")]
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentClasses() {
    var db = new School_DBEntities();
    var xx = db.Students.ToList().Select(q=>new Student()
    { 
        Student_ID=q.Student_ID,
        First_Name=q.First_Name,
        Classes=q.StudentsClasses.ToList().Select(e=>new Class()
        {
            Class_code=e.Class,
            Class_Name=db.Classes.FirstOrDefault(v=>v.Class_code==e.Class).Class_Name
        }).ToList()
    });
   
    return xx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<StudentClasses> StudentClasses { get; set; }
    }

    class Classes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<StudentClasses> StudentClasses { get; set; }
    }

    class StudentClasses
    {
        public int ClassesId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public Classes Classes { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mathClass = new Classes()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Math"
            };

            var englishClass = new Classes()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "English"
            };

            var nermine = new Student()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Nermine"
            };

            var nermineMath = new StudentClasses()
            {
                Classes = mathClass,
                Student = nermine
            };

            var nermineEnglish = new StudentClasses()
            {
                Classes = englishClass,
                Student = nermine
            };

            var data = new List<StudentClasses>() { nermineEnglish, nermineMath };
            var result = data.Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    Code = x.Student.Id,
                    Name = x.Student.Name,
                    Classes = new { Id = x.Classes.Id, Name = x.Classes.Name }
                }).ToList();

            result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            //returns 
            //{ Code = 1, Name = Nermine, Classes = { Id = 1, Name = English } }
            //{ Code = 1, Name = Nermine, Classes = { Id = 1, Name = Math } }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Rod, I don't want the data to be static I want to get it from SQL server and have the following return { Code = 1, Name = Nermine, Classes = { Id = 1, Name = English } }
            //{ Code = 1, Name = Nermine, Classes = { Id = 1, Name = Math } }

Comment: Hey nermine, the query should be almost the same, just change the data source for a db set of type studentclasses

Comment: @NermineBoulos something like: DbContext.StudentClasses.Select(x => x...